# Omni_auth logs out on backbone save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, omniauth

I have a rails app using backbone, but when I call save, the server is redirecting to login - even though I'm already logged in (the page on which the backbone model is found is only shown after logging in).

I'm using backbone.matroyshka for nested models - but removing it doesn't solve the problem.

Here's the code that calls save on the model in the view:

```
    var view = this;

// save model
this.model.save(null, {
    success: function(model, response) {
        view.$('#saving').hide();
        view.notice('Saved!', 'success');
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        view.$('#saving').hide();
        view.notice(response, 'error');
        console.log('save failed ' + response, view.model.get('url'));
    }
});
```

Prior to the model.save request, there is an AJAX request to retrieve data using jQuery AJAX:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: serverUrl,
        data: { url: model.get('url') },
        dataType: "json", 
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
            model.set(data);
        },

        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('lookup share url failed ' + error, this.get('source'),         this.get('about'));
            this.trigger('load:fail');
            if (options.error) {
                options.error(this, error);
            }
        }
    });
```

The model.save receives a 302 found from the server, redirecting it to the login page.
The controller for the resource is protected by

```
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create]
```

signed_in_user is in a session helper taken straight from a tutorial on using omni_auth

```
  def signed_in_user
unless signed_in?
  store_location
  redirect_to login_path, notice: "You must be logged in to find out what they do."
end
```

end

I have another page that saves with AJAX (not backbone), and it works fine (also requires a signed in user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Backbone but it sounds like it's not sending the [CSRF token](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

This article should be helpful:
http://ngauthier.com/2011/02/backbone-and-rails-forgery-protection.html